# How to support legacy url alias' and/or support multiple url alias' (Conditional Pathauto?)

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I am migrating a site from wordpress and need to preserve my url structure whilst supporting native pathauto urls in the future (for new content)

Overall Drupal's clean url process is almost identical to wordpress but I am finding some small discrepancies and with around 2k posts to migrate over I need a programmatic way to do this that won't feel like I'm trying to roll a keg up hill.

I was thinking of inserting in the old wordpress url as `field_legacy_slug` and then I could create paths based on that, but... as far as I know pathauto doesn't have any conditional abilities and I'd want to use a `field_legacy_slug` only if it exists, else use a standard token based pathauto pattern (site.com/2011-01-01/title-of-post)

I also don't think creating multiple alias' for content is advisable (aka letting wordpress url alias' exist beside the native pathautos) - but I am course asking *you* for insight into this :)

Creating node paths on import myself and allowing pathauto to catch new nodes seems like my only option but I'd hate for someone to run an "Update path alias" and ruin it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the new-for-Drupal-7 [Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) module will provide what you need. Have not used it myself yet, but I used Path Redirect (which provides similar functionality for Drupal 6) to solve a similar problem. I generated a two-column table of values (old URL in one column, new URL in the other), and fed that to Path Redirect -- problem solved. Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I wanted! "Common API for loading, saving, and deleting redirects." - oh baby. Just need to add a new operation to my already large import bash script

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect). I use it to redirect all `/node/###` queries to the proper path. All the content could have the new URLs, but the old URLs would redirect to the canonical URL. This would solve your inadvertent 'Update path alias' problem, and also help with SEO magic.

Comment: I would agree with paxswill. If you are concerned that you may not achieve 100% coverage I would suggest also using the [Search404](http://drupal.org/project/search404) module to catch any missed urls.

Comment: If it goes to a 404 it's too late, my search ranking will die along with the dead link, I'll look into the Global Redirect more though, thanks!

Comment: So to be clear - You are suggesting that I add 2 aliases - the wordpress url as well as the drupal alias? and global redirect to force the use of (or redirect away from) one of them?

Comment: Redirect the Wordpress URLs to node/<nid>, then let Global Redirect redirect node/<nid> to whatever you've set up as an alias in Pathauto. You could even use mod_rewrite to do the Wordpress->node/<nid> redirect, as it's just a one-time migrate.

Comment: I have around 2.5 thousand posts so it's not really viable to do mod_rewrite rules for each one...